# Infiniband interface doesn't route IPoIB traffic

Tags: routing, infiniband

I have blocks of hosts that I'm provisioning using `Puppet` in exactly the same way, they have identical hardware (same blade chassis), and are definitely connected in all the same ways where interfaces on some are not working the same as others. These are all Infiniband interfaces, so I'm able to test them with commands like `ibping` and `ibsysstat`, which shows that they have working UVERBS/RDMA connections. For example:

```
master# ibsysstat 29
sysstat ping succeeded
```

where the node with that LID that isn't working quite right has:

```
node10# ibstat
CA 'mlx4_0'
    CA type: MT4099
    Number of ports: 1
    Firmware version: 2.11.1250
    Hardware version: 1
    Node GUID: 0x...
    System image GUID: 0x...
    Port 1:
        State: Active
        Physical state: LinkUp
        Rate: 40
        Base lid: 29
        LMC: 0
        SM lid: 26
        Capability mask: 0x02594868
        Port GUID: 0x...
        Link layer: InfiniBand
```

but, when I just do a simple `ping` to the IPoIB IP address it sits there not connecting. Other commands  like `ibping` are also definitely passing traffic, and data shows up when adding `-d` showing debug output. I can see the pings go out when I watch the interface using `tcpdump`, but nothing coming in. Meanwhile, right next to it is a host with the same everything that works just fine. The routing tables all like right to me also, and match hosts that work. On a host that doesn't work:

```
default via 10.10.0.1 dev em1 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.10.0.0/24 dev em1 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.0.110 metric 100 
10.11.0.0/24 dev ib0 proto kernel scope link src 10.11.0.110 
169.254.0.0/16 dev ib0 scope link metric 1005
```

and on one that does:

```
default via 10.10.0.1 dev em1 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.10.0.0/24 dev em1 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.0.108 metric 100 
10.11.0.0/24 dev ib0 proto kernel scope link src 10.11.0.108 
169.254.0.0/16 dev ib0 scope link metric 1004
```

The only thing different is the metric in the last route, but that shouldn't matter. Also of note, these hosts worked before they were reprovisioned. So I'm almost positive it's not hardware.

I'm at a bit of a loss now and any ideas would be appreciated.

Edit: Update with dmesg error

I found something in the output of `dmesg` for the interface in question that only exists on the hosts that don't work. The error

```
ib0: failed to modify QP to RTR: -22
```

unfortunately this isn't very helpful, and there's not much that comes up related in searches.

Perhaps also worth noting, the hosts in question can ping the switch IP address, and the switch can ping the hosts on their associated IPs.

Comment: While probably not related, I would uninstall avahi. Zeroconf should have no place on enterprise servers.

Comment: It's not actually installed, the script `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-ib` from OFED adds a route in for some reason. I've removed that and no change.

Comment: 169.254 is usually a sign it is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in kernel 3.10.0-862.11.1 to 3.10.0-862.11.6 (see [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3568891) and [here](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=15193)).

Essentially, if you update the kernel to 862.11.1-862.11.6, a bug in drivers/infiniband/core/verbs.c where a semi-colon was left out causes all reliable connected (rc) messages to fail while unreliable datagram messages will work. You can either patch this driver, or boot from an earlier kernel to work-around this issue until the updated kernel resolves this issue.

Comment: Holy hell, that's exactly what it was. I spent a bunch of time trying to fix this and never thought to check the kernel versions because the ones that didn't work were built within a day of the ones that did. Thanks.